# I am getting the following error using ns2 help to debug. can't read "udp1": no such variable while executing "$cbr1 attach-agent $udp1"

Tags: ns2

`set ns [ new Simulator ]`
`set trf [ open 1.tr w ]`
`$ns trace-all $trf`
`set namf [ open 1.nam w ]`
`$ns namtrace-all $namf`

# The below code is used to create the nodes.

`set n0 [$ns node]`
`set n1 [$ns node]`
`set n2 [$ns node]`

## This is used to give color to the flow of packets.

`$ns color 1 "red"`
`$ns color 2 "green"` 
`$n0 label "Source/udp0"`
`$n1 label "Source/udp1"`
`$n2  label “destination”`

## providing the link

`$ns duplex-link $n0     $n2 10Kb 100ms DropTail`
`$ns duplex-link $n1     $n2 5Mb  200ms DropTail`

## set the queue size b/w the nodes

`$ns set queue-limit $n0 $n2 10`
`set cbr1 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]`
`$cbr1 attach-agent $udp1`

## The below code sets the udp0 packets to red and udp1 packets to blue color

`$udp0 set class_ 1` 
`$udp1 set class_ 2`

## The below  code is used to connect the agents.

`$ns connect $udp0       $null3`
 `$ns connect $udp1       $null3`

## The below code is used to set the packet size to 500

`$cbr1 set packetSize_ 500Mb`

## The below code is used to set the interval of the packets,

`$cbr1 set interval_ 0.001`
`proc finish { } {`
`global ns namf trf`
`$ns flush-trace`
`exec nam 1.nam &`
`close $trf` 
`close  $namf`
`exit 0`
`}`
`$ns at 0.1 "$cbr0 start"`
`$ns at 0.1 "$cbr1 start"`
`$ns at 10.0 "finish"`
`$ns run`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an agent and then attach it to a node

```
set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0
```